# df reporting weird file usage info

Tags: ubuntu-9.04, df

This is on an ubuntu machine running jaunty (9.04).  Yesterday there was 30 something gigs free, now df is reporting:

```
    /dev/sda1             9.2G  5.1G  3.7G  59% /
    none                  966M  264K  965M   1% /dev
    none                  970M     0  970M   0% /dev/shm
    none                  970M  140K  970M   1% /var/run
    none                  970M     0  970M   0% /var/lock
    none                  970M     0  970M   0% /lib/init/rw
    /dev/sda3             219G  207G  179M 100% /home
```

why is it reporting 219G size, 207G used, but only 179M available on /dev/sda3?  i know filesystems free space tends to look a little funny at times due to their very nature, but i have never seen this before....

Comment: Did you remove any files on /home which were in use? 

(In that case they do not get remove from disk until the program using them closes their file handle).